# How to configure which sound card jack2 will use

Tags: arch-linux, configuration, jack

I've installed `jack2` as a substitution for `jack` from official repositories (I'm on Arch Linux):

```
# pacman -S jack2
```

I need to use jack2 because it provides `jackd` (it's needed for another application), while `jack2_dbus` [does not provide it](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/JACK_Audio_Connection_Kit).

According to [this manual](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/JACK_Audio_Connection_Kit), in order to configure such parameters as sampling rate, one should use `jack_control`, but it is available only for `jack2_dbus` (which I cannot use).

I also have read [this article](http://w3.linux-magazine.com/issue/67/JACK_Audio_Server.pdf), but unfortunately, I can't follow it (it was written for `jack`, apparently `jack2` does not include `jackstart` anymore):

```
[mark@arch ~]$ jackstart -R -d alsa -d hw:1U -p 512 -r 48000 -z s
bash: jackstart: command not found
```

I would like to somehow set default audio card, because when an application uses jack on my system, it uses card with `0` index and this is not what I want (I want, say, audio card with index `2`).

Here is my `~/.asoundrc`:

```
#
# ALSA Configuration File
#

defaults.ctl.card 2
defaults.pcm.card 2
defaults.dmix.rate 44100
defaults.dmix.channels 2
```

Is there configuration file that controls which audio card will be used when an application invokes `jackd`? Any other means to set the parameter (and others)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only choose audio card once when starting jackd. You can list cards available to alsa with `aplay -l` (aplay is part of alsa-utils). Then you can start the jack daemon, and pick the card to use with `jackd -d alsa -d hw:<card>,<device>`.

Comment: So I should always start it myself before starting any program that will use `jack` in order to control parameters of sound?

Comment: Is it OK to add a script on starting X server (for example) for activating this daemon?

Comment: That should work. I don't think that there is a correct way to do it. Another alternative would be to create a systemd service, although I haven't tried this myself.